# how to install bastille to kali linux

Tags: linux, security, kali-linux

I'm just asking why kali show this phrases "E: Package bastile has no intallation candidate" .[image]

Comment: Kali isn't a good distro to learn Linux on and please post text instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you need to update the kali repositories

First: You need to know your kalis version,SANA,ROLLING... by running this command:

```
lsb_release -a
```

After that if it is a ROLLING:

```
echo -e "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And if it is a SANA run:

```
echo -e "deb http://old.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list
```

After doing that run:

```
apt-get update 
apt-get update --fix-missing
```

Finally you can run your install command, and it should work fine.